# Azure DevOps deploy to a website virtual application (Virtual Folder)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, azure-devops

I have created a pipeline to deploy a web API .Net Core 3.1 project on IIS.

The issue is that this application is an "application" under a common domain, shared by other applications:

```
- my-domain.com    => bind to https://my-domain.com
  - Application1   => reachable with https://my-domain.com/Application1
  - Application2   => reachable with https://my-domain.com/Application2
  - Application3   => reachable with https://my-domain.com/Application3
  - Application4   => reachable with https://my-domain.com/Application4
```

Each application has its own project solution, and they run on their different application pool in IIS

Recently Azure DevOps has introduced as mandatory the bindings for each deploy, so now I need to write something and it can't be the bindings of the parent site otherwise it goes in an error saying that there is already a website with this bindings.

Which is the right way to publish it?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in our project, and was able to get it working by setting up the release pipelines for the virtual applications with only the "IIS Web App Deploy" task (without the "IIS Web App Manage" task). Does that work for you?